# React-Admin <SimpleForm> component doesn't trigger the "UPDATE" action in the data provider

Tags: react-admin, admin-on-rest, json-server

So I'm using the [ra-data-json-server](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-json-server) as a data provider and the bult in `<SimpleForm>` component as a form for the `<Edit>` view, and I'm facing a pretty strange issue, as it says in [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.1/CreateEdit.html#the-simpleform-component), when submitted, the `<SimpleForm>` forces data provider to make a `PUT` request to the API, but in my case it does not.
Here's my `Edit` view compnent:

```
export const UserEdit = props => {
  return (
    <Edit {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ArrayInput source="applications">
          <SimpleFormIterator source="applications">
            {/* some inputs */}
          </SimpleFormIterator>
        </ArrayInput>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};
```

And the admin component itself:

```
export const AdminComp = () => {
  return (
    <Admin
      loginPage={CustomLoginPage}
      authProvider={authProvider}
      locale="ru"
      i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
      <Resource
        name="students"
        list={UserList}
        edit={UserEdit}
      />
    </Admin>
  );
};
```

And everytime I get into the `Edit` view and hit the save button it just doesn't do anything.

I managed to make it at least call the `update` in data provider, but it would call it with the old form data even though it was modified already.

I also tried reinstalling `react-admin` to the latest version which is what some people reccomended but it didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem and cannot figure it out. Did you happen to solve the problem?

Comment: I am also having a similar issue, though for me the Save button simply redirects to the list view.